# How to draw clickable pin point on blackberry map?

Tags: blackberry, dictionary

From last day I am searching how to draw clickable pin on lat long on blackberry maps in os 5.0. I draw image on particular lat long but I want to go another screen by clicking that image.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had done like this using Google maps.

```
    String initial = "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n" +
    "<html> \r\n" +
    "<head> \r\n" +
    "  <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" /> \r\n" +
    "  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> \r\n" +
    "  <script src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\" \r\n" +
    "          type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\r\n" +
    "</head> \r\n" +
    "<body>\r\n" +
    "  <div id=\"map\" style=\"width: 360px; height: 390px;\"></div>\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "  <script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n" +
    "    var locations = [";
String second= " ];\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {\r\n" +
        "      zoom: 8,";
String centerPoint ="";
String finalpart = " mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP\r\n" +
        "    });\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "    var marker, i;\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  \r\n" +
    "      marker = new google.maps.Marker({\r\n" +
    "        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),\r\n" +
    "        map: map\r\n" +
    "      });\r\n" +
    "\r\n" +
    "      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {\r\n" +
    "        return function() {\r\n" +
    "          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);\r\n" +
    "          infowindow.open(map, marker);\r\n" +
    "        }\r\n" +
    "      })(marker, i));\r\n" +
    "    }\r\n" +
    "  </script>\r\n" +
    "</body>\r\n" +
    "</html>";

html=new StringBuffer();
html.append(initial);


 point = "['"+name[i]+"',"+lat[i]+","+ lon[i]+","+i+"],";
 html.append(point);

 html.append(second);
   html.append(centerPoint);
   html.append(finalpart);
   //System.out.println("Plot is"+html.toString());
   BrowserFieldConfig _bfConfig = new BrowserFieldConfig();        
  _bfConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE,BrowserFieldConfig.NAVIGATION_MODE_POINTER);
  _bfConfig.setProperty( BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE );
  _bfConfig.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.USER_AGENT, "MyApplication 1.0");
  BrowserField myBrowserField = new BrowserField(_bfConfig);

   myBrowserField.displayContent(html.toString(), "");
   HorizontalFieldManager horf=new HorizontalFieldManager(HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
   horf.add(myBrowserField);
   add(horf);
```

When i click the pin, it will show the name of the user.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to another recent question.  In the other question, the poster was asking how to draw a custom image for the map pin (marker).  It's not clear to me whether you want a custom image as your map pin, or not.  But, if you do, and are happy to use [MapField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html?net/rim/device/api/lbs/MapField.html), then

[see this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878296/119114).

You just don't need to worry about the part where I draw a **second** layer on the pin, for the round user profile picture.

But, you will still override the `paint()` method to draw your custom pin, then determine the location of the user touch/click on the map, and calculate distance from that touch/click to the pin, to determine which pin was clicked.  Handling the touch/click will work differently for touchscreen and non-touchscreen devices, but I link to the API methods you will need to use for both.

Comment: @Newts, My answer is not for Google Maps.  It's for the `MapField` class, which is a part of the BlackBerry APIs.  Did you want the solution to draw the pin in the separate built-in maps app (leaving your app)?  If so, please clarify this in your question.  But, if your app shows embedded maps with `MapField`, or a subclass of `MapField`, then my answer will work.